# MySQL trigger inserting 0 after a view change used in the trigger

Tags: mysql, view, triggers, mariadb

I wonder if anyone has any idea what is the reason for trigger to insert a 0 into a column after view that is used inside of it had a change. Situation is like this:

Table A has AFTER INSERT trigger => trigger is set to run a view and then insert the results into Table B.

This so far worked flawlessly. Recently I had to do a small change in the view used by the trigger. The change was for one of the columns to return avg value and not sum. Manually running the view returns correct data in the changed column. Yet the trigger would always return 0 from the changed column.

I managed to repair the trigger by just adding white space and saving, but this is not ideal. Am I missing something or is this normal behavior on MySQL?

Trigger

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` TRIGGER trigger_A
AFTER INSERT 
   ON table_A FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    select 
        date_time
        , lines_
    INTO
        @date_time
        , @lines_
    from view_A where date_time = concat(substr(sysdate(),1,13),':00:00');
    select count(*) into @hourly_check from able_B where date_time = concat(substr(sysdate(),1,13),':00:00');
    if ( @hourly_check = 0 ) then 
        insert into table_B (date_time, lines_)
        values (concat(substr(sysdate(),1,13),':00:00'), '0');
    end if;
    UPDATE `DATABASE`.`table_B`
    SET
        `lines_` = @lines_,
    WHERE `date_time` = @date_time;
END
```

View

```
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `view_A` AS
    SELECT 
        CONCAT(SUBSTR(`table_A`.`date_time`, 1, 13),
                ':00:00') AS `concat(substr(date_time,1,13),':00:00')` as date_time,
        ROUND(AVG(`table_A`.`lines_`), 1) AS `round(avg(lines_),1)` as lines_ -- this is where I changed from sum() to avg()
    FROM
        `table_A`
    GROUP BY CONCAT(SUBSTR(`table_A`.`date_time`, 1, 13),
            ':00:00');
```

Table_A

```
CREATE TABLE `table_A` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `lines_` text DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_date_time` (`date_time`)
);
```

Source data

| date_time | lines_ |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-05-17 09:02:00 | 7 |
| 2023-05-17 09:04:00 | 18 |

Table_B

```
CREATE TABLE `table_B` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `lines_` text DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_date_time` (`date_time`)
);
```

Expected insert from trigger

| date_time | lines_ |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-05-17 09:00:00 | 12.5 |

Insert after view change

| date_time | lines_ |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-05-17 09:00:00 | 0 |

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Here is a setup to re-create the issue

```
CREATE TABLE `table_A` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `lines_` text DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_date_time` (`date_time`)
);

CREATE TABLE `table_B` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `lines_` text DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_date_time` (`date_time`)
);

create unique index IX_date_time on table_B (date_time);

CREATE 
VIEW `view_A` AS
    SELECT 
        CONCAT(SUBSTR(`table_A`.`date_time`, 1, 13),
                ':00:00') as date_time,
        ROUND(SUM(`table_A`.`lines_`), 1)  as lines_
    FROM
        `table_A`
    GROUP BY CONCAT(SUBSTR(`table_A`.`date_time`, 1, 13),
            ':00:00');

delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_A
AFTER INSERT 
   ON table_A FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    select 
        date_time
        , lines_
    INTO
        @date_time
        , @lines_
    from view_A where date_time like '2023-05-19 09%';
    insert into table_B (date_time, lines_)
        values (@date_time, @lines_)
    on duplicate key update date_time = @date_time
        , lines_ = @lines_;
END;
//
delimiter ;

insert into table_A (id,date_time,lines_)  values 
('11', '2023-05-19 09:02:00', '7'),
('12', '2023-05-19 09:04:00', '18'),
('13', '2023-05-19 09:06:00', '7'),
('14', '2023-05-19 09:08:00', '18'),
('15', '2023-05-19 09:10:00', '9'),
('16', '2023-05-19 09:12:00', '25'),
('17', '2023-05-19 09:14:00', '15'),
('18', '2023-05-19 09:16:00', '50'),
('19', '2023-05-19 09:18:00', '49'),
('20', '2023-05-19 09:20:00', '50'),
('21', '2023-05-19 09:22:00', '2'),
('22', '2023-05-19 09:24:00', '5'),
('23', '2023-05-19 09:26:00', '2'),
('24', '2023-05-19 09:28:00', '5'),
('25', '2023-05-19 09:30:00', '2'),
('26', '2023-05-19 09:32:00', '5'),
('27', '2023-05-19 09:30:00', '2'),
('28', '2023-05-19 09:32:00', '5');
```

Steps are like this:

1. Run all the queries above
2. When you select from table_B you will see

| id | date_time | lines_ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ** | 2023-05-19 09:00:00 | 276 |

3. Now edit view via alter view option in MySQL Workbench ( that is how I do it) and change ROUND(SUM(`table_A`.`lines_`), 1)  as lines_ => ROUND(AVG(`table_A`.`lines_`), 1)  as lines_
4. Delete data from both tables and insert again
5. Select form table_B again, it will still show same result for sum (276) instead of avg

Result

| id | date_time | lines_ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ** | 2023-05-19 09:00:00 | 276 |

Expected

| id | date_time | lines_ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ** | 2023-05-19 09:00:00 | 15.3 |

6. If you now go and alter the trigger and add white space anywhere and apply, delete and insert data again into both tables, it will show the correct avg value of 15.3

This is what my problem is, changing view will not reflect it in trigger. It will still use 'old' view instead the updated one

I'm using v10.2.15 MariaDB on Fedora 28.

Comment: 'Yet the trigger would always return 0 from the changed column.' -  you can't RETURN anything from a trigger so how do you know this are you inferring, it by what ends up in target? Please add table definitions, sample data trigger code and expected outcome as text.

Comment: @P.Salmon I know because trigger works in principle, it will insert data into Table B with the exception of 0 in the changed column.

Comment: XY-problem. Post the task itself, not only your attempt to solve it. And add complete sample, see [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), #5 and #3.

Comment: @ErgestBasha just done that

Comment: is (AVG(`sic_report`.`lines_`) a typo in the published code when you are selecting from table_a?

Comment: @P.Salmon just typo on the example, corrected it

Comment: The select in the trigger should fail in the trigger with 13:10:19  Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'date_time' in 'field list' which is to be expected since the view does not assign aliases in it's select. Personally I would prefer declared variables over user defined variables, explicit datatype conversions over implicit, and insert ..on.duplicate key rather than mucking about with conditional tests to establish pre-existence

Comment: @P.Salmon I have taken your suggestion and changed the trigger to just use insert with on duplication clause. I have as well updated my question with an example that shows the problem I have

Comment: `If a trigger is loaded into cache, it is not automatically reloaded when the table metadata changes. In this case a trigger can operate using the outdated metadata.`, see [Trigger Limitations](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/trigger-limitations/). Some options: `4. TRUNCATE data from table_A and DELETE from table_B` or `4.1 FLUSH TABLES table_A` or `DROP TRIGGER and CREATE TRIGGER`.

Comment: @wchiquito and that is the answer I was looking for, thank you, can you put it as answer so I can give you an upvote